# How to remove primary color when button clicked

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I click on the `button` the buttons color changes from `#F74422` to primary color for some time. How to remove that primary color?

```css
.click-button {
    background-color: #F74422;
}
```

```html
<button ion-button class="click-button" full (tap)="clickme()">Click</button>
```

Comment: I tried 100 times. It didn't changed. so we need to know that `some time`. May be it is related to the framework you have used.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai  the snipet above just work with ionic framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the **[Overriding Ionic Sass variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)** section from the docs, when you declare a button to be of a color, for example, `primary` behind the scenes Ionic will apply the following styles for an android button:

```
$button-md-background-color:           color($colors-md, primary)   
$button-md-background-color-activated: color-shade($button-md-background-color)
$button-md-background-color-hover:     $button-md-background-color
```

Something similar happens as well for ios buttons. That's why you see the primary color when you change the `background-color` using a css style rule. The `activated` and `hover` states of the button still use a color obtained from the `primary` color defined by Ionic.

The *Ionic way* of changing the button background color would be to add a new color in the `variables.scss` file:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222222,
  newcolor:   #F74422 // <--- Here!
);
```

And then use that color in the button, using the `color` attribute:

```
<button ion-button color="newcolor">Secondary</button>
```

That way Ionic will create all the style rules to make the button to use that color for every *state*.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for ionic 4:

```html
<ion-button class="my-button" expand="block" shape="round">TEXT</ion-button>
```

```css
.my-button {
  --background: #4daf7c;
  --background-activated: #4daf7c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its happen due to focus and visited 
You need to override

```
.click-button:focus
```

and

```
.click-button:visited
```

as well